# C++ cout outputting 0 incorrectly

Tags: c++

For some reason, this block of code is incorrectly giving zero as the `cout` despite that being incorrect.

```
// HouseholdSize.cpp - This program uses a bubble sort to arrange up to 300 household sizes in
// descending order and then prints the mean and median household size. 
// Input:  Interactive.
// Output:  Mean and median household size. 

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   // Declare variables.
        
   const int SIZE = 300;    // Number of household sizes
   int householdSizes[SIZE];    // Array used to store 300 household sizes
   int x; 
   int limit = SIZE;
   int householdSize = 0;
   int pairsToCompare;
   bool switchOccurred; 
   int temp;
   double sum = 0;
   double mean = 0;
   double median = 0;

   // Input household size      
   cout << "Enter household size or 999 to quit: ";
   cin >> householdSize;
   
   // This is the work done in the fillArray() function
   x = 0;
   while(x < limit && householdSize != 999)   
   {
      // Place value in array.
      householdSizes[x] = householdSize;
      // Calculate total of household sizes
      
      x++;    // Get ready for next input item.
      cout << "Enter household size or 999 to quit: ";
      cin >> householdSize;
   }  // End of input loop.
        
   
   // Find the mean
   mean = sum/limit;

cout<<"Mean: "<<mean; 

   
   // This is the work done in the sortArray() function

   // This is the work done in the displayArray() function
 
 // Print the mean

   // Find the median
   
   // Print the median
for(int i = 0; i<limit; i++) {

  for(int j = i+1; j<limit; j++){

     if(householdSizes[j] < householdSizes[i]){

        temp = householdSizes[i];

        householdSizes[i] = householdSizes[j];

        householdSizes[j] = temp;       }    } }

median= (householdSizes[(limit-1)/2]+householdSizes[1+(limit-1)/2])/2.0;

if((limit - 1)%2==0){

   median = householdSizes[limit/2];

}

cout<<endl<<"Median: "<<median; 

            
   return 0;
} // End of main function
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as from your question, the problem doesn't seem to come from the sorting function, but rather input/output.

Comment: @JaMiT the problem is, the code that is looping is code that was already provided for me.

Comment: ```   // Input household size      
   cout << "Enter household size or 999 to quit: ";
   cin >> householdSize;
   
   // This is the work done in the fillArray() function
   x = 0;
   while(x < limit && householdSize != 999)   
   {
      // Place value in array.
      householdSizes[x] = householdSize;
      // Calculate total of household sizes
      
      x++;    // Get ready for next input item.
      cout << "Enter household size or 999 to quit: ";
      cin >> householdSize;
   }  // End of input loop.```

Comment: i think this is the part causing the problem

Comment: @Yellowslotcar **Edit** the question to provide more information. Providing code in the comment section doesn't do much

Comment: alright. will do.

Comment: @JaMiT alright, editied

Comment: I just did edit it. i'm still new to this site, sorry :)

Comment: So, it's not breaking the loop even when you entered `999`? Without that, the loop would continue for 300 numbers

Comment: ...you know what... maybe i should go to bed.
i'm an idiot

Comment: ok.... so the problem wasn't an infinite loop... it's an entirley diffrent problem

Comment: the mean and median are not being output correctly

Comment: Now, to get a good [mre], you should replace the input loop with a loop that simply sets elements of `householdSizes` to values that demonstrate the problem. Otherwise, I *will* choose inputs for which `0` is the correct answer. ;)

Comment: Can you demonstrate to us why the output should not be zero? You output `mean` and `median`. Which lines should set these to non-zero values? What are the values of the variables used on the right side of the assignment operator on those lines? (You could stream those to `std::cout` to get a quick look at them.)

Comment: i'm too sleepy to figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

The median appears to be correct, but for the mean you are initializing the sum to 0 but not incrementing it so `mean = sum/limit;` is always going to be 0.